# AWS Route 53 list records by creation date

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I'd like to get a list of all DNS records in my hosted zone that have been created recently, for example in the last 24 hours.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

No, as useful as it'd be I don't believe Route53 tracks record creation time.

If you happened to save the change IDs you get when creating records, you can get the SubmittedAt time of the change request later. But if you're saving that, you may as well just save the record creation time yourself...

```
$ aws route53 change-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id ZXXXXXXXXXXX --change-batch file://sample.json

{
    "ChangeInfo": {
        "Status": "PENDING", 
        "SubmittedAt": "2018-07-10T19:39:37.757Z", 
        "Id": "/change/C3QYC83OA0KX5K"
    }
}


$ aws route53  get-change --id /change/C3QYC83OA0KX5K

{
    "ChangeInfo": {
        "Status": "INSYNC", 
        "SubmittedAt": "2018-07-10T19:39:37.757Z", 
        "Id": "/change/C3QYC83OA0KX5K"
    }
```